# Manhua/manga/manhwa where the female lead is given a second chance at her life and gets revenge on her ex-husband and his mistress

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I am looking for a historical/ancient Chinese manga where the female lead lost her child because of her husband and his mistress. The female lead **dies while her new-born child is pushed back into her womb,** then she is given a second chance at life. I can't remember exactly when she is reborn, but it was before she remarries her ex-husband.

She marries another guy. I don't remember his exact position, but I think he was like a military commander. **He wears a mask since his face is disfigured because of a fire when he was little; I think he lost someone important there. I think the female lead later discovers that he was faking to be disfigured as to avoid suspicion or something like that.**

I remember that the female lead had like something or a destiny that whoever she marries becomes the emperor or something. I'm not sure what it was, but I think it had something to do with a phoenix.

I remember that the female lead dies alongside her most loyal maid and promised that in her next life she would treat her better, or I think that it was the maid that promised that she would serve her in her next life.

**So the female lead helps her now husband to win in countless battles because she has knowledge of the future.** I think somewhere along the way, her husband is curious of how she knew all of this.

That's all I remember.